# Having the right winner listed for each game Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program with Python that will ask the user for the scores for 5 games. I then need the winner of each match to be printed at the end. The part I'm having an issue with is getting the right winner for each match to print. I can only use lists, for loops and if/else statements. I'm new to programming so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Description: The program will accept the number of points that each team scored in the 5 matches and print out the data along with the winner. The winning team is that one that wins the most matches. Note: It is not necessarily the team that scores the most number of points.

```
games = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
winner = ["Team 1", "Team 2"]
gamesresults = 0
team1_scores = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
team2_scores = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
matches = ["Match 1", "Match 2", "Match 3", "Match 4", "Match 5"]

for games in range(5):
    team1_scores[games] = int(input("Enter the score from team 1 from match {}?".format(games+1)))
    team2_scores[games] = int(input("Enter the score from team 2 from match {}?".format(games+1)))
    games += 1

#the section i'm having problems with
for games in range(5):
    if team1_scores[games] > team2_scores[games]:
        winner = "Team 1"
    else:
        winner = "Team 2"

    gamesresults = [team1_scores, team2_scores, winner]

#this is ok
print(" ", "Team 1", "Team 2", "Winner")

for i in range(5):
    print("Matches", i+1, team1_scores[i], team2_scores[i], winner)

if team1_scores > team2_scores:
    print("The Winner is Team 1")
else:
    team2_scores > team1_scores
    print("The Winner is Team 2")
```

Comment: What are the rules of the game, like how id the winner decided? Is it the most total score or something else?

Comment: The program will accept the number of points that each team scored in the 5 matches and print out the data along with the winner. The winning team is that one that wins the most matches. Note: It is not necessarily the team that scores the most number of points.

Comment: _The part I'm having an issue with is getting the right winner for each match to print._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should be counting the number of matches won by each team, instead, you are overriding the `winner` variable in each for loop.

You need to save each count of won games in two different variables, and then compare them:

```
# save both amounts
won_by_team1 = 0
won_by_team2 = 0
for games in range(5):
    if team1_scores[games] > team2_scores[games]:
        won_by_team1 += 1
    else:
        won_by_team2 += 1


# compare them
if won_by_team1 > won_by_team2:
    winner = "Team 1"
else:
    winner = "Team 2"
```

This is not a very nice code, but it will help you to understand the logic that needs to be applied.

Once you understand this, I would recommend to rewrite this code in order to make it look nicer.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think your code isn't clean code, but this code is work

```
games = list()
team1_scores = list()
team2_scores = list()
winner = list()

for games in range(1, 6):
    team1_scores.append(int(input("Enter the score from team 1 from match {}?".format(games))))
    team2_scores.append(int(input("Enter the score from team 2 from match {}?".format(games))))

for team1_score, team2_score in zip(team1_scores, team2_scores):
    if team1_score > team2_score:
        winner.append("Team 1")
    else:
        winner.append("Team 2")

for i in range(len(winner)):
    print("In match {} score of team 1 is : {} and score of team 2 is : {} and winner is {}".format(i+1, team1_scores[i], team2_scores[i], winner[i]))

print("The Winner is " + max(winner))
```